# AttributeError: module 'asyncio' has no attribute 'create_task'

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await, python-3.6, python-asyncio

I'm trying to `asyncio.create_task()` but I'm dealing with this error:

Here's an example:

```
import asyncio
import time

async def async_say(delay, msg):
    await asyncio.sleep(delay)
    print(msg)

async def main():
    task1 = asyncio.create_task(async_say(4, 'hello'))
    task2 = asyncio.create_task(async_say(6, 'world'))

    print(f"started at {time.strftime('%X')}")
    await task1
    await task2
    print(f"finished at {time.strftime('%X')}")

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Out:

```
AttributeError: module 'asyncio' has no attribute 'create_task'
```

---

So I tried with the following code snippet (`.ensure_future()`) instead, without any problem:

```
async def main():
    task1 = asyncio.ensure_future(async_say(4, 'hello'))
    task2 = asyncio.ensure_future(async_say(6, 'world'))

    print(f"started at {time.strftime('%X')}")
    await task1
    await task2
    print(f"finished at {time.strftime('%X')}")

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Out:

```
started at 13:19:44
hello
world
finished at 13:19:50
```

---

## What's wrong?

---

[**NOTE**]:

- *Python 3.6*
- *Ubuntu 16.04*

---

[UPDATE]:

With borrowing from <sub>@[user4815162342](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1600898/user4815162342)</sub> [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53247626/3702377), my problem solved:

```
async def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    task1 = loop.create_task(async_say(4, 'hello'))
    task2 = loop.create_task(async_say(6, 'world'))

    print(f"started at {time.strftime('%X')}")
    await task1
    await task2
    print(f"finished at {time.strftime('%X')}")

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The [`create_task`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.create_task) top-level function was added in Python 3.7, and you are using Python 3.6. Prior to 3.7, `create_task` was only available as a [method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.create_task) on the event loop, so you can invoke it like that:

```
async def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    task1 = loop.create_task(async_say(4, 'hello'))
    task2 = loop.create_task(async_say(6, 'world'))
    # ...
    await task1
    await task2
```

That works in both 3.6 and 3.7, as well as in earlier versions. [`asyncio.ensure_future`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-future.html#asyncio.ensure_future) will work as well, but when you know you're dealing with a coroutine, `create_task` is more explicit and is the [preferred](https://github.com/python/asyncio/issues/477#issuecomment-268709555) option.

Comment: Thank's for the answer, but I encountered with this error: `RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'main' was never awaited`

Comment: @BenyaminJafari Please edit the question to include the new code you are testing.

Answer (score -1):

I did like this

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
        asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(scheduled(4))
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.